# MATLAB: How to find nodes that are in any cycle in a directed graph?

Tags: matlab

Let's say the adjacency matrix of a directed graph A is given by

```
0     1     0     0
1     0     0     0
0     1     0     0
0     0     0     1
```

Then the nodes in any cycle are

```
1 (1->2->1)
2 (2->1->2)
4 (4->4)
```

Is there a efficient way to get the list of nodes in any cycle?

I know summing up A,A^2,A^3,A^4... and searching up for non-zero diagonal works, but I am working on a high-dimensional matrix and it takes too long.

Thank you.

Comment: I think this is called "[closed paths](http://www-math.ucdenver.edu/~wcherowi/courses/m4408/gtln4.html)"/"[cycles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_(graph_theory))" and "[loops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_(graph_theory))". (Getting the terminology right might help with finding an [existing solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_(graph_theory)#Cycle_detection).) See also [`graphisdag`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/graphisdag.html).

Comment: @Dev-iL Thanks for you comment, I changed the question a bit
+ I guess graphisdag is a test for a cycle in a graph, but I am interested in getting the nodes in any cycle.

Comment: @rahnema1 Hi, thanks for your help. I think the code you uploaded gives a result for only a short cycle (i.e., returning in one step). With the matrix A in my original question, it gives me only 4...

Comment: @rahnema1 Yes it does! Now the only worry is that there's a for-loop but I think I can vectorize those. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`dfsearch`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.dfsearch.html) with `edgetodiscovered` option to find start and end nodes of all cycles. Then use a loop to find [`shortest path`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.shortestpath.html) from an end node to a start node:

```
G = digraph(A);
e = dfsearch(G, 1, 'edgetodiscovered', 'Restart', true);
n = size(e,1);
result = cell(1,n);
for k = 1:n
    result{k} = shortestpath(G, e(k,2), e(k,1), 'Method', 'unweighted');
end
```

To avoid the loop you can create a dummy node and add edges from the node to all end nodes of the cycles. Then use [`shortestpathtree`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.shortestpathtree.html) to find  the shortest paths from the dummy node to start nodes of the cycles. Note that each path in the result starts with the dummy node that shoud be remove from the path.

```
G = digraph(A);
e = dfsearch(G, 1, 'edgetodiscovered', 'Restart', true);
n = size(e,1);
dummy = numnodes(G) + 1;
G = addedge(G, repmat(dummy, n, 1) , e(:,2));
result = shortestpathtree(G, dummy , e(:,1), 'OutputForm', 'cell', 'Method', 'unweighted');
```

Comment: Hi, I was thinking unique(e) after having e finishes the problem. Would you kindly let me know if this makes sense?

Comment: I'm not sure but if `result{k} = shortestpath(G, e(k,2), e(k,1), 'Method', 'acyclic');` produces the correct result it my be fatser.

Comment: Sorry unique does not work here. I am still desperately looking a way to get rid of that loop because I am working on more than thousands of nodes.